# How to remove row from table / disable the submit button permanently once user clicked on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, disabled-input

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'xxx', amount: 13, years: 2, interest: 2},    
        {name: 'yyy', amount: 23, years: 1, interest: 3},
        {name: 'zzz', amount: 123, years: 4, interest: 4}
    ];
    $scope.sub = function()
    {
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
    <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td><input type=text ng-value="item.years" ng-model="first"></td>
                <td><input type=text ng-value="item.amount" ng-model="amount"></td>
                <td><input type=submit ng-click="sub()"></td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>           



</body>
</html>
```

I above snippet what happening is when user  clicks on submit button, data gets store in db and returns with updated. So what I want is once I received updated that particular click row should be removed or that button should become PERMANENTLY disabled irrespective of refresh.

I try to implement it disabled but once it received updated it making all the button disabled.

please Help me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the row or disable the button in your `sub()` function.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'xxx', amount: 13, years: 2, interest: 2, disabled: false},    
        {name: 'yyy', amount: 23, years: 1, interest: 3,disabled: false},
        {name: 'zzz', amount: 123, years: 4, interest: 4,disabled: false}
    ];
    
    $scope.sub = function(name)
    {
       for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++){
          if($scope.items[i].name === name){
             if($scope.disableButton){
               $scope.items[i].disabled = true;
             }else{
               $scope.items.splice(i,1);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
     <label>Disable button (will delete if not checked):
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disableButton">
     </label><br/>
    <table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
        <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td><input type=text ng-value="item.years" ng-model="first"></td>
                    <td><input type=text ng-value="item.amount" ng-model="amount"></td>
                    <td><input type=submit ng-disabled="item.disabled" ng-click="sub(item.name)"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>           
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I want to get Index of clicked submit button row how can I get that. you can mention this in comment. @rckrd

Comment: @Mohammed You have it right there in the loop, the variable `i`. As you can see, `i` is used when disabling the button `$scope.items[i].disabled = true`

Comment: ya got it right. But simply asking if I need to pass it through ng click then the how it will be. I applied this in my assignment on click $index but it always returning 0. @rckrd

Comment: Well I guess you do have the access to the index: `ng-click="sub($index)"`  and then `$scope.sub = function(i)
{
  $scope.items.splice(i,1);
}`

Comment: Will try and let  you know too. @rckrd

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need an async solution:
use private ($$) properties for ng-disabled

**JS:**

```
$scope.sub = function(item){
    item.$$disabled =true;

    // you need an async solution
    function saveItem(item){
        // use angular.toJson(item) can auto remove $$ property
    }
    saveItem.then(res => {
        // successfully saved
    }).catch(err => {
        item.$$disabled =false
    })
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="sub(item)" ng-disabled="item.$$disabled">
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrrobin/brvx666k/